# h.264 live stream

Tags: inputstream, h.264, red5, flash-media-server, wowza

After reasearching for a few days, i m still lost with this issue:

I have a webcam connected over WiFi to my Android device.
I wrote an Android app to connect to a specified Socket of the webcam (IP and port). From this Socket i get an InputStream which is already encoded in H.264. Then i redirect this InputStream from the android device to my server, where i managed to decode it to images/frame by using Xuggler.

I would like to stream my webcam live to the internet to a flash player or something.
I know i have to use Wowza, FMS or RED5 for this.

My problem is, that i dont understand how to proceed with the InputStream i have. All examples i ve read need a mp4/flv or other container file to stream from... but i have a continuous live InputStream.
Some other examples consider using Flash Encoder. But my InputStream is already encoded in H.264.

This is a general understanding question. Please advise me on how to solve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have following options -

1. Encode in flv container. Yes you can transmit live stream using using flv container. You can set the 'duration' field in the header to be arbitrary long. e.g youtube use this trick for live streaming.
2. you can encode the stream into RTMP. ffmpeg has code for rtmp code which can be used for understand, or i believe there are other opensource rtmp muxers available.
3. convert the stream into HLS, there are flash based HLS player available.

Comment: thank you. Do you have an example of how to tell ffmpeg to fetch the data to publish from my InputStream/Socket connection. All examples i came across showed how to stream from a existing file.

Comment: i have not tried this but it should be possible. http://www.mail-archive.com/libav-user@ffmpeg.org/msg01899.html

Comment: thx for your effort. This seems a little bit too much for my skills. I m using Java. Do you have experience with Xuggler? Because i m able to decode the stream to a BufferedImage. But i dont know how to create a flv or mp4 out of the InputStream.

Answer (score 0):

why flash if I may ask, hope you know that HTML5 video tag now directly accepts h264 encoded videos.

Comment: Its not going to be an answer for above question. you better post it as a comment.